# Can we customize the stylesheet for success popup for fileUpload(Beta) Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to update the font size of on the pop up message that comes after fileUpload is successful with `FileUpload(Beta)` option.

I tried using and updating the existing SLDS and those are working fine updating the existing fileUpload UI but not really the success pop up that shows up after file selection

[image]

Comment: Yes, we can do that. If the pop-up is in the same frame.

Comment: Hey  itzmukeshy7, Thanks for Response. May you have any example on how to achieve this as I dont exactly know to access modal Specific Code, any stylesheet changes I do, are getting applied to File Selector Section and not really the Prompt/Modal

Comment: First, make it the way you like then copy the Style rules from developer console put it in a static resource and finally load this static resource in the component using the `<ltng:require styles="staticResourcePath" />` and boom!